# React native paper DataTable.Cell overflow text causes hide full text

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

Below code using `DataTable.Cell`.

If text bigger than column width it hide text

Please help need to display text if text bigger than  column width  need to break text in next line.

```js
<DataTable.Row
  style={{ flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap', paddingLeft: 1, borderColor: 'green', borderWidth: 2 }}>
  <DataTable.Cell
    style={{
      flex: 3,
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      borderColor: 'yellow',
      borderWidth: 2,
      height: auto,
      overflow: 'visible',
    }}>
    <View style={styles.rowbox}>
      <Text style={styles.stnname}>Test 1</Text>
      <Text>Day:1</Text>
      <Text>Distance:0</Text>
    </View>
  </DataTable.Cell>
  <DataTable.Cell numeric>Cell 1 2</DataTable.Cell>
  <DataTable.Cell numeric>Cell 1 3</DataTable.Cell>
</DataTable.Row>
<DataTable.Row
  style={{ flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap', paddingLeft: 1, borderColor: 'green', borderWidth: 2 }}>
  <DataTable.Cell
    style={{
      flex: 3,
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      borderColor: 'yellow',
      borderWidth: 2,
      height: auto,
      overflow: 'visible',
    }}>
    <View style={styles.rowbox}>
      <Text style={styles.stnname}>Test 2 Test 2 Test 2</Text>
      <Text>Day:1</Text>
      <Text>Distance:0</Text>
    </View>
  </DataTable.Cell>
  <DataTable.Cell numeric>Cell 2 2</DataTable.Cell>
  <DataTable.Cell numeric>Cell 2 3</DataTable.Cell>
</DataTable.Row>
```

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      padding: 16,
      marginTop: 20,
      zIndex:1
    },
    autocompleteContainer: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    descriptionContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      width:'100%',
      alignItems:  'stretch'
    },
    itemText: {
      fontSize: 15,
      paddingTop: 5,
      paddingBottom: 5,
      margin: 6,
      color: '#000',
      
    },
    infoText: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      fontSize: 16,
    },
    autodropsection:{
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
      flex:1,
    },
    containerMain: {
      flex: 1,
      padding: 0,
      marginTop: 0,
    },
    datrow1:{
      flex: 4, 
      flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    tableheader:{
      backgroundColor : "#2375b3",
      color:'#ffffff',
      fontSize: 24,
      fontWeight: '700',
      flex: 2,
    },
    tableheadertitle:{
      fontSize: 14,
       fontWeight: '500',
       color:'#fff',
       textAlign:"center"
    },
     tableheadercell:{
      color:"#fff",
      fontSize:24,
    },
    cell:{
      color:'#fff',
      fontSize:24,
      flexDirection:'column'
    },
    stnname:{
      fontSize: 12, 
      fontWeight: '700',
      color:'#333',
      textAlign:"left",
      flexWrap:'wrap',
      alignContent:'flex-start'
    },
    rowbox:{
      paddingTop:10,
      paddingBottom:10,
      paddingLeft:0,
      paddingRight:0,
      flexDirection:'column',
      textAlign:'left',
      justifyContent:'flex-start',
      flex: 1,
      borderWidth:2,
      borderColor:'red',
      flexWrap:'wrap',
      width:'100%'
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Get the same issue, after big search i simply abandon this idea and start to use.

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-easy-grid/

Is realy simple to construct the same structure, like a table, after o just need to set border if you want, and done, simple and easy like Html.

Answer (score 4):

Use a View (with `justifyContent: 'center'`) instead of DataTable.Cell to achieve the multilined cell

Source: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/2381#issuecomment-734155600

Comment: This is the winner. This one helped me. The one marked as answer isn't really an answer.

Answer (score 0):

simply added properties out of style:
numberOfLines={2}

Comment: Whenever writing code snippet, use formatting to make it more clearer to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataTable.Title
  textStyle={styles.cell}
  numberOfLines={2}
>
  This line is about to wrap `enter code here`
</DataTable.Title>
```

Add `numberofLines` props to `Datatable.Title`, it will assign two lines to text.

Answer (score -1):

You can use css properties:
`textOverflow: 'clip', whiteSpace: 'normal'`
on your cell.

Example:

```js
<DataTable.Row>
  <DataTable.Cell textStyle={styles.cell}>Too long text, which should be multiline.</DataTable.Cell>
</DataTable.Row>
    
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cell: {
    textOverflow: 'clip',
    whiteSpace: 'normal',
  },
});
```